# How to handle Yodlee MFA while refreshing?

Tags: yodlee

What is the flow with Yodlee MFA account? Do I need add MFA request to every refresh action or only once at the first time login to provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFA needs to be passed during every refresh if the site is MFA.  Follow the Add and Refresh flow diagram present on on portal.  Also, you should try using [Fastlink 2.0](https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0)  - a great UI to add, edit user accounts.